# How to verify the position of characters from the column?

Tags: command-line, scripts, regex

I have a column MBI contains 11 characters. Out of these 11 characters:

1. 2nd, 5th, 8th, and 9th characters will always be a letter.
2. Characters 1, 4, 7, 10, and 11 will always be a number.
3. The 3rd and 6th characters will be a letter or a number

I wrote the code separately.

**Step 1:**

```sh
cut -c 3,6 ACO_SAMPLE.txt > alphanumeric

while read line
do

if echo "$line" | grep -q  '^[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$'
then
   echo "$line is a valid"
else
   echo "$line is invalid"
fi

done < alphanumeric

rm -f alphanumeric
```

**Step 2:**

```sh
cut -c 2,5,8,9 ACO_SAMPLE.txt > alphabet

while read line
do

if echo "$line" | grep -q  '^[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]$'
then
   echo "$line is a letter"
else
   echo "$line is not a letter"
fi

done < alphabet

rm -f alphabet
```

**Step 3:**

```sh
cut -c 3,6 ACO_SAMPLE.txt > alphanumeric

while read line
do

if echo "$line" | grep -q  '^[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]$'
then
   echo "$line is a valid"
else
   echo "$line is invalid"
fi

done < alphanumeric

rm -f alphanumeric
```

Now, I need to club all the codes into one. I'm not sure how. Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: What is a "column MBI"? Please [edit] your question to include a minimal example of your input data and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You can match this with a single regular expression (split over multiple lines for clarity). You may need to match case insensitive depending on your input data.

```
^               # Start of string
[0-9]           # Number
[a-z]           # Letter
[a-z0-9]        # Letter or Number
[0-9]           # Number
[a-z]           # Letter
[a-z0-9]        # Letter or Number
[0-9]           # Number
[a-z]           # Letter
[a-z]           # Letter
[0-9]           # Number
[0-9]           # Number
$               # End of string
```

Or as a single line

```
^[0-9][a-z][a-z0-9][0-9][a-z][a-z0-9][0-9][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9]$
```